# How-To get the current keyboard layout on Alpine Linux?

Tags: alpine-linux, keyboard-layout

We work on many machines, direct or via SSH, not on all machines we are using the same keyboard layout. I found solutions for ArchLinux and Ubuntu (and Windows), but no solution works on Alpine-Linux.

How can I get the **current keyboard-layout** on `Alpine-Linux`? On Terminal (/bin/ash) or via script?

The layout can configured with `setup-keymap us us` but I found no solution to get the current layout back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently used keymap is in the configuration file `/etc/conf.d/loadkmap`

Comment: Thanks! In my case I got `.../us.map.gz` ok, where do I get the "sub-map", so the second `us`?

Comment: us basically means us us, it might be a little bit confusing, but if you try for example the `us-mac` variant, the filename in the directory will be `us-mac.bmap.gz`